# VBA to create a timeline in Visio

Tags: excel, vba, visio, timeline

How do we create a timeline diagram in Visio using VBA scripts?
I am trying to do this from excel. I have written the VBA script to open the visio diagram and create a basic shape. I want to create a timeline diagram. 
Similar to basic_u.vss and visMSDefault, are there any parameters that are required while creating a timeline diagram?
Below is the code snippet that I am using.

```
Option Explicit

Sub VisioFromExcel()

Dim AppVisio As Object
Dim vsoCharacters1 As Visio.Characters
Dim lX As Long
Dim dXPos As Double
Dim dYPos As Double

'Const visSectionCharacter = 3
'Const visCharacterSize = 7

Set AppVisio = CreateObject("visio.application")
'Set AppVisio = CreateObject("VisioTimelineVBA")
AppVisio.Visible = True

AppVisio.Documents.AddEx "", visMSDefault, 0 'Open Blank Visio Document
'AppVisio.Documents.AddEx "", visMSDefault, 0 'Open Blank Visio Document
AppVisio.Documents.OpenEx "basic_u.vss", visOpenRO + visOpenDocked   'Add Basic Stencil

dXPos = AppVisio.ActivePage.PageSheet.Cells("PageWidth") / 2
dYPos = AppVisio.ActivePage.PageSheet.Cells("PageHeight") / 2

For lX = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    AppVisio.Windows.ItemEx(1).Activate
    AppVisio.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop AppVisio.Documents.Item("BASIC_U.VSS").Masters.ItemU("Square"), dXPos, dYPos

    Set vsoCharacters1 = AppVisio.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(lX).Characters
    vsoCharacters1.Begin = 0
    vsoCharacters1.End = 0
    vsoCharacters1.Text = CStr(Cells(lX, 1).Value)

    AppVisio.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(lX).CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = "36 pt"


Next

Set AppVisio = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to drop a square, you can use the DrawRectangle method on the Page object, though if you get into performance issues you can use the DropMany method to drop a bunch of square shapes, which is faster than dropping them or drawing them one at a time.

Comment: Jon Fournier, This was just an example of trying to create a visio page. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

Option Explicit

Sub VisioFromExcel()

```
Dim AppVisio As Object


Dim docsObj As Visio.Documents 
Dim DocObj As Visio.Document
Dim pagsObj As Visio.Pages


Set AppVisio = CreateObject("visio.application")

AppVisio.Visible = True

Set docsObj = AppVisio.Documents
Set DocObj = docsObj.Add("Timeline.vst")

Set pagsObj = AppVisio.ActiveDocument.Pages


Set AppVisio = Nothing
```

End Sub